# there is not any design form when i try with Xamarin.forms in vs2019?

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

i installed vs2019 on my windows 10 . when i try to start work with xamarin there is not any form for designing . and when i double click on xamarin.form i see this message : "  . can anybody help me please ?
[THIS PROJECT CANNOT BE VIEWED IN THE OBJECT BROWSER BECAUSE IT IS UNAVAILABLE OR NOT YET BUILT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnZW1.png)
this problem occur just on xamarin.form projects

i upgraded .netframework , reinstalled vs2019 , installed vs2022 but the problem still is here

Comment: XF does not have a design tool.

Comment: tnx for answering . how to fix that ?

Comment: You can try right-clicking the project name in the project's Solution Explorer, then *build* the project, and then running the project on the platform.